# ASP.NET ORM for High Scalable Websites

Tags: design-patterns, orm, llblgenpro, .nettiers

**Which is the best option for High Scalable Websites or Enterprise Applications:**

1. LBLGen
2. .NetTiers
3. LinqToSQL
4. NHybernate
5. Repository Pattern (CodePlex)

If any other available let me know.

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004295/asp-net-mvc-and-orm-selection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [ORMBattle.NET](http://ormbattle.net) - high performance is usually related to scalability. Of course, mainly indirectly: high performance is related to code perfection in general; being really fast implies deep understanding of all the background issues and the ability to deal with them.

Note (or disclaimer): I'm one of persons related to creation of ORMBattle.NET, as well as one of [DataObjects.Net](http://www.dataobjects.net) authors.

Comment: Thanks! Great site it will sure be helpful.

Comment: Also note this site is highly misleading....as in, what it **literally** says is technically true, it is often irrelevant, as it measures things you would not do.

Comment: So what it _must_ measure? I'm asking it because there were lots of argues around this, and still no any _exact_ answer. If you know it, just drop the link here ;)

Comment: And, it's highly recommended to _visit FAQ @ ORMBattle.NET_ - lots of points like this are covered there.

Answer (score 0):

CSLA (http://lhotka.net/) is an excellent Business Object Framework that will definitely scale up to commercial enterprise applications.

Comment: Have you used it in any Enterprise App or at least a High Traffic Website scenario?

Comment: Yes, we used CSLA to build a custom CMS; www.goodwood.com is one example.

Comment: I would caution here as CSLA uses "Reflection" to maintain object state.  For web applications, when was the last time you had n levels of undo built into an application?  The reason you do not see this as the state maintenence costs you memory and in the end scalability.  More scalable models will tend to be stateless.  I tend to prefer to keep only what state I absolutely need.  "Undo" is great for enterprise applications, but the question here was for "Websites".  I would not use CSLA in this case.